Is baselining necessary in a random intercepts model of longitudinal data with repeated measurements?
I have m samples with n repeated measurements on each sample. Samples are divided equally into treatment and control. I use a random effects modeling strategy with random intercepts for each individual. Given that I control for random intercepts do I still have to normalize each individual's measurement by their measurement at time 0 ie prior to the application of the first treatment?

Welcome to CV. How exactly have you specified your model? Some common approaches include raw values at each timepoint (including baseline) or change at each post-baseline timepoint with baseline as a covariate. Note that both of these still include the baseline somewhere; discarding it entirely is almost certainly suboptimal if not outright wrong.
